# Using SCSS In Material UI React directly

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-ui

I have some issue using scss directly in material ui, because not all styles are applied. Tried to use `makeStyle`, but because I use class component, it gives warning about invalid hook call.

The style :

```
.table-header {
  background-color: #005CAA; //only this style works
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I call in in `TableCell` component from Material UI

```
 <TableCell className="table-header">Invoice Number</TableCell>
```

For the scss file, I import it in parent component `App.tsx`, or I need to import the file directly in the Table component? Thx

Comment: what warning did you get?

Comment: for using makeStyle function inside class component? It give `invalid hook call`.

Comment: For class component, you should use ```withStyles``` and ```makeStyles``` for function component. Read more here: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/

Answer (score 2):

I follow the makeStyles approach as it's recommended way of overriding the material-ui styles, else you'd have to use !important in your css/scss files to override the material-ui styles.
https://mui.com/styles/basics/

```
// component file
import React from 'react';
import { TextLineStyles } from './styles';

export default function TextLine({ text }) {
  const classes = TextLineStyles()
  return <div className={classes.root}>
    <div data-title="line" >
      <div data-title="text">
        {text}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}



// style.js
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const TextLineStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        '& [data-title="line"]': {
            borderTop: `1px solid lightgray`,
            '& [data-title="text"]': {
                color: 'red' // scss like nesting
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: makeStyles is now deprecated. do not use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS/SCSS class in MUI component, you should import the file directly in the Table component. But, it's not good to use SCSS with MUI component, you should use `makeStyles` or `withStyles` to style the MUI component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best practice, in fact thats why I ended up in this post.
Here it explain how to use scss with material-ui: https://www.markmakesstuff.com/posts/mui-css-modules

1. "Just install node-sass"
2. "if you're working with an app you initialized with a script like create-react-app, you are in luck. No webpack edits necessary. Just give your module a name that ends with ".module.scss""
   OTHERWISE
   2') You need to "make some minor edits to your webpack config"
3. "You can then import your module with a name then use that to refer to your classes when writing your fancy JSX"